# проблема с установкой pcapy

Tags: python

при попытке импрота библиотеки pcapy получаю:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\qqq\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b11mxoc0\pcapy_afada5757e8647e7b1e6c4e5a6d1c066\setup.py", line 49, in <module>
          save_init_posix = sysconfig._init_posix
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'distutils.sysconfig' has no attribute '_init_posix'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
`
```

пробовал обновлять pip, импорт через --use-deprecated

Comment: Какая версия Python? Если 3.12, пробуйте откатить до 3.11

Comment: приведённый вывод скорее похож на результат установки, а не импорта.

Comment: да, перепутал, уже изменил (проблема с импортом>>проблема с установкой)

Comment: insolor, версия 3.11